# Find all python files in linux file system

Tags: command-line, python, find

How can I search my entire Linux filesystem for all python files (files with extension `.py`)? I know I can do `find -name filename` but how can I do it for file type?

Comment: What about python files that don't have the extension `.py`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all python files will have the file extension `.py` - Try running `grep -rni python /usr/bin` for example). Most of these scripts will have a 'shebang' (or hashbang) line (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python`, `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`). This informs the interpreter of the script which program needs to be used to run it, and you could search for this to find python files

However, you can also use the file's mimetype (usually along the lines of `text/x-python`) to find it:

```
find / -type f | while read in ; do if file -i "${in}" | grep -q x-python ; then echo "${in}" ; fi ; done
```

Where `/` is your intended search directory.

With `find` you could also add the `-executable` option to look for only executable files. Also the use of `-type f` restrict find to look only for files - you could change this and then show symbolic links etc as well *(some scripts are contained in `/usr/lib` etc and symlinked to `/usr/bin/` etc)*. Many more options are available, you can see these by running `man find`.

`file` should be able to guess the filetype even if the file has no extension etc (using the shebang line etc) - see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207276/52956).

To removed any `find: ‘/.../FILE’: Permission denied` etc errors, you can run the script as root (using `sudo bash -c "COMMAND"`, opening a shell with `sudo su` etc), and/or simply append `2>/dev/null` to the find command.

Comment: Yes ! Exactly that !  Linux/Unix doesn't care about extensions , and that's exactly the way I'd approach this question. I also think  `find` + `-exec` flag would be a better alternative, and just pipe output to `grep` or `awk`. That will bring down the line to two pipes only.

Comment: If you really are going to `find | while read`, then do `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r in`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#line-108

Comment: Thanks, I knew someone would say 'u could do this' :) , I didn't k now the parsing Ls thing would come up :D  You can add your own versions if you want... I can't right now

Comment: @Wilf well, you are examining every file in the system. Who knows what filenames will come up.

Answer (score 8):

`-name '*.py'` since `-name` accepts a pattern.

Mind the single quotes.

Comment: yes but also *.cgi can be a python file ...

Answer (score 6):

`sudo find / -name "*.py"`

You only need `sudo` to avoid `Permission denied`s (since you're searching from the root).

Comment: You need to be careful with 'bare' globs in situations like this: if there happens to be a file or files in the current directory that match `*.py` the shell will expand the glob and pass the result of *that* to the `find` command. Bottom line: quote or escape any such patterns i.e. use `"*.py"` or `'*.py'` or `\*.py`